# Implement scrollbar in Canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I wanted to implement a scrollbar on the mainframe in Tkinter however that is not possible thus I have to use Canvas. With canvas, I am able to implement a scrollbar and use other widgets accordingly. Everything worked fine until I attempted to add widgets into the Canvas.

Error Faced: Scrollbar looks off and unable to scroll

So what did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Code (Python 3.8.2)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("950x600")

# create canvas
canvas = Canvas(root, width=932, height=600, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="black")
canvas.grid()

# create a scrollbar
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

# Test the ability to scroll
for x in range(30):
    Label(canvas, text="test").grid(row=x)

root.mainloop()
```

Note: I only want to add other widgets, including scrollbar using only grid manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to add

**#1** a frame inside a canvas

**#2** binding an event (configure) that changes the canvas view thing with scroll

**#3** create a window with the given frame

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("950x600")

# create canvas
canvas = Canvas(root, width=932, height=600, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="black")
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
# create a scrollbar
f=Frame(canvas)#1
canvas.grid()
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))#2
canvas.create_window((0,0),anchor='nw',window=f,width=932)#3
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
# Test the ability to scroll
for x in range(300):
    Label(f, text="test").grid(row=x)

root.mainloop()
```